# in outlook, can you click on a task that was referring to an email to get to the containing folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

i flag and categories lots of emails,  is there anyway on the todo bar to click on a task that is really just a flagged email and find the containing folder of the email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply hover the email in the todo list and it will tell you what folder it is sat in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the "Arranged By: Due Date" column heading and select "Folder", this will group the items by where they are stored.